# Translations per language and per profile

Tags: profile, translation, language, translation-workbench

Currently SF supports out of the box Translation Workbench where we could provide translations for each field, label etc. based on selected language.

But one of our latest requirement is to support translations specific for profiles in scope of the same language. E.g. we have tech savvy users vs lamers, for latter we would need to name stuff much simpler, using 'human' language, provide longer descriptions etc - but they both are using same language.

Unfortunately SF doesn't support custom languages to add a few to host such profile specific translations.

Are we missing something here? Is there any way to achieve this still staying withing SF? If not, are there any well known external products to deal with translations and which easily integrates with SF to satisfy our goal?

Any help and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The alternatives, which you no doubt know, are: 1) invest time and money to train people in learning the tech expressions. 2) have the tech savvy users deal with human language. What is the problem with the second alternative?

Comment: @SanderdeJong I guess the idea is to kind of provide group of users with their own unique experience, i.e. application would be sort of personalized, be more closer to you. As a developer I would prefer browser or text editor with more technical wordings, than full of literature slang)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Platform-Only Languages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm)?

There are 3 types of languages in Salesforce:

1. Fully Supported Languages
2. End-User Languages
3. Platform-Only Languages

Salesforce provides translations for standard labels for Fully Supported and End-User languages. For Platform-Only languages it falls back to English (except for some cases).

If you enable Platform-Only languages in the Language Settings (under Company Settings), you can create translations for it like any other language using the Translation Workbench, *Rename Tabs and Labels*, Custom Labels etc.
You can then use one of these Platform-Only languages for the tech savvy users. You just need to tell them to use f.i. Spanish (Honduras) instead of 'regular' Spanish to see the technical labels instead of the normal labels.

Comment: It's a bit of a work around, but it might work.

Comment: Yep, we had idea like this one, but put it aside for now. The main concern with using ecsotic languages to emulate flavour of already supported languages is problem with locale, i.e. it may change displayed date and number format, timezone etc. And even if we may find something close to original language (like you suggested, Honduras for Spanish), we may need more similar languages than supported by platform, i.e. 4 variations for Spanish. But yep, that's the only more or less valuable option we've figured out so far. Thanks.

Comment: Locale is controlled by a separate setting though, so I don't think that should be a big concern. And there are 82 platform only languages, so it will go a long way. Remember, you don't necessarily need a language that's close to its original language (such as the example) as long as you can explain it to the end user. I'm sure a tech savvy user will understand that there are sometimes limitations and workarounds needed to solve them, so they'll understand that Bosnian is used as the technical version of Italian (random example)